# Receiving another system's network packets

Tags: network, mirror

I'm looking for a way to receive all network traffic intended to go to my desktop PC, on another device.

I believe I need either a network hub or network switch with monitoring port for this, but not sure which of the two.

Comment: Sadly, product recommendations are off-topic here.

Comment: Product or resource recommendations are explicitly off-topic for SE sites, except [softwarerecs.se] and [hardwarerecs.se].

Comment: @RonTrunk, the question isn't asking for a product recommendation.  That looks like "What model number should I buy?".  They are asking "Do I use a switch or hub to do what I want to do?".  That's simply a person who doesn't know the difference between a switch and hub to perform this task.  This question should be reopened.

Comment: @MikePennington The specific request for recommendations was deleted after I commented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hub is the cheaper option, but you will be limited to 100 Mbps and as you will be operating in half duplex mode, you will only get a fraction of that bandwidth and it is shared, both upstream and downstream.

Switches are more expensive, but you can go to 1 Gbps or beyond.  You can also simulate a hub by turning off MAC learning instead of using a monitor port.

So if you want cheap, go with hub, if you want bandwidth, go with switch

Comment: Then the switch does sound like the better option, what exactly do I have to look for in a switch's specification to make sure it can do what I want?

Comment: You need to look for the facility to do port mirroring or disable MAC learning, you will only find these features in a managed switch, but not all managed switches support these features, so make sure it does

Answer (score 1):

Port Mirroring enabled Switch is what you would need to do this. A simple google search will give you the answer. Search for something like this "Provides network monitoring, traffic prioritization and VLAN features" in google.